# When specifing a column in creating a table in PostgreSQL, what does "meta jsonb" mean?

Tags: postgresql

When specifing a column in creating a table in PostgreSQL, what does `meta jsonb` mean?

Answer (score 0):

`meta` is the column name and its type jsonb.

It's basically a column to store unstructured metadata if needed.

If you've used MongoDB it would be similar to storing a document as a column value.

Answer (score 0):

meta is the column name and its type jsonb.

jsob is a data type to store a binary representation of json.

**Sample json :-**

```
{
"name":"mahesh",
"age":25
}
```